# SELECT Access to SQL 2005 View with Restricted Access to Underlying Table

Tags: sql, security, sql-server-2005, view, schema

I have created a SQL userid, role, and schema in a SQL 2005 database. I have created a SQL View under this schema that selects from a table in the dbo schema. However, I don't want the SQL user to be able to select from this table.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW [MySchema].[vwMyView]
AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.MyTable
```

The user has access to the *MySchema* view and can query *vwMyView* with no problems. However, they can also SELECT from dbo.MyTable.

How do I restrict all access to *dbo.MyTable*? If I deny the SELECT permission on the dbo schema, the user cannot select from the view.

Comment: have you tried to revoke their access to the view?  

REVOKE privilege_name 
ON object_name 
FROM {user_name |PUBLIC |role_name}

Comment: I don't want to revoke their access to the View, only the Table that the View uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
REVOKE select 
ON tablename
FROM {user_name}
```

just revoking select doesn't in itself doesn't revoke other permissions.

Then do an explicit grant select on the view.   Not sure if this will work as I have never tried it this way but worth a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the problem. The OP still wants the user to be able to select from the view, just not directly from the underlying table.

Comment: This statement revokes the SELECT permission on the view. The SQL user should have access to SELECT from the View, but not the Table.

Comment: correct.  I got the table and view requirements crossed up.  Edited the answer to give something to try. now I'm curious if this will work

Comment: Thanks, Brian, but this did not change anything. The user_name was still able to select from both the view and the underlying table.